# Adding header mediator in WSO2 sequence or proxy

Tags: soap, wso2, soapheader

I am trying to add a custom soap header to a sequence, but eclipse design view doesn't like it and won't let me save it.

I would like to add the following code under "Header tag" ( using Header Mediator)

```
<p1:Header xmlns:p1="http://www.XYZ.com/XSD"> 
                    <Version>1.5</nVersion> 
                    <Code>XYZ</Code> 
                    <Type>ABC</Type> 
                    <Ver>1.1/1.2</Ver> 
                    <Org>DIS</Org> 
</p1:Header>
```

I am aware that header mediator syntax is "header name="xyz"  action="" value="" but I want to build this custom header as a response to a request. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Header Mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Header+Mediator) to specify your own XML for SOAP Header. This feature is supported from ESB 4.5.0 onwards.

Just specify your custom header inside `<header>`.

You can use either source view or user interface to define the proxy. If you are trying on Eclipse, it probably might not support this new feature. I have to check on that.

But you can just define a proxy using the standalone ESB product.

Here is a sample proxy I just tested using WSO2 ESB 4.6.0.

```
<proxy name="Test"
      transports="https http"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="disable">
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <header>
           <p1:Header xmlns:p1="http://www.XYZ.com/XSD">
              <p1:Version>1.5</p1:Version>
              <p1:Code>XYZ</p1:Code>
              <p1:Type>ABC</p1:Type>
              <p1:Ver>1.1/1.2</p1:Ver>
              <p1:Org>DIS</p1:Org>
           </p1:Header>
        </header>
        <send>
           <endpoint>
              <address uri="http://localhost:8899/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
           </endpoint>
        </send>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence>
        <header>
           <p2:Header xmlns:p2="http://www.ABC.com/XSD">
              <p2:Hello>World</p2:Hello>
           </p2:Header>
        </header>
        <send/>
     </outSequence>
  </target>
  <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:8899/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl"/>
</proxy>
```

Following is how the request is sent from WSO2 ESB and response it returns

Request:

```
POST /services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "urn:getQuote"
userAgent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: 127.0.0.1:8899
Connection: Keep-Alive

2f3
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://services.samples/xsd" xmlns:ser="http://services.samples">
   <soapenv:Header><p1:Header xmlns:p1="http://www.XYZ.com/XSD">
              <p1:Version>1.5</p1:Version>
              <p1:Code>XYZ</p1:Code>
              <p1:Type>ABC</p1:Type>
              <p1:Ver>1.1/1.2</p1:Ver>
              <p1:Org>DIS</p1:Org>
           </p1:Header></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getQuote>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <ser:request>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:symbol>WSO2</xsd:symbol>
     </ser:request>
      </ser:getQuote>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
0
```

Response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <p2:Header xmlns:p2="http://www.ABC.com/XSD">
     <p2:Hello>World</p2:Hello>
      </p2:Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getQuoteResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.samples">
     <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:GetQuoteResponse" xmlns:ax21="http://services.samples/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ax21:change>4.14429919417878</ax21:change>
        <ax21:earnings>13.29119739059685</ax21:earnings>
        <ax21:high>-84.84231581484899</ax21:high>
        <ax21:last>85.60273864169663</ax21:last>
        <ax21:lastTradeTimestamp>Sun Jul 28 00:31:19 IST 2013</ax21:lastTradeTimestamp>
        <ax21:low>88.1046394678485</ax21:low>
        <ax21:marketCap>-6540210.216549877</ax21:marketCap>
        <ax21:name>WSO2 Company</ax21:name>
        <ax21:open>89.52770935798549</ax21:open>
        <ax21:peRatio>24.07637499909879</ax21:peRatio>
        <ax21:percentageChange>-5.198506483420408</ax21:percentageChange>
        <ax21:prevClose>-79.72095845982282</ax21:prevClose>
        <ax21:symbol>WSO2</ax21:symbol>
        <ax21:volume>9801</ax21:volume>
     </ns:return>
      </ns:getQuoteResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Note the values in `<header>` tags.

I hope this helps.

Thanks!